# centering the full page background image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code from this link http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
    <script>
        $(function() {   

              var theWindow        = $(window),
                  $bg              = $("#bg"),
                  aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

              function resizeBg() {

                if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                    $bg
                      .removeClass()
                      .addClass('bgheight');

                } else {
                    $bg
                      .removeClass()
                      .addClass('bgwidth');
                }

                $bg.style.marginTop = (-theWindow.height() / 2) + 'px';
                $bg.style.marginLeft = (-theWindow.width() / 2) + 'px';

              }

              theWindow.resize(function() {
                resizeBg();
              }).trigger("resize");

            });
    </script>
    <style>
    #bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-2;}
    .bgwidth { width: 100%; }
    .bgheight { height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <body>
       <div id="caseStudies">
            <img src="images/caseStudy01.jpg" alt="Case Study 1" id="bg">
        </div>
</body>
```

but I want to center the background image. I have tried to this by using the following code:

```
$bg.style.marginTop = (-theWindow.height() / 2) + 'px';
$bg.style.marginLeft = (-theWindow.width() / 2) + 'px';
```

which isn't working. Am I referencing the correct values?

Comment: Without your HTML, we can't really help you.

Comment: The best way to center the background image is to set CSS style: `background-position: 50% 50%`.

Comment: I have updated the question to show my html and css :)

Comment: YEAH, lets use jquery to style \o/

Comment: Ark if you would like to point me in the direction of a better solution, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with this:

```
    $bg.style.marginTop = ($bg.height()/2-theWindow.height() / 2) + 'px';
    $bg.style.marginLeft = ($bg.width()/2-theWindow.width() / 2) + 'px';
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still not centering the image, I am completely new to js so it may be that I am putting it in the wrong place?